# Где ошибка в коде (TypeError ), Python

Tags: python, type-error

Взял пример с рекурсией, чтобы понять как работает
дописал 2 строки для ввода чисел массива с клавиатуры и запуска функции в интерпретаторе:

```
def sum(list):
    if list == []:
        return 0
    return list[0] + list[1:]
list = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
sum(list)
```

выдает ошибку TypeError :

```
                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d4a1a84fa932> in <module>
      5 
      6 list = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
----> 7 sum(list)

<ipython-input-8-d4a1a84fa932> in sum(list)
      2     if list == []:
      3         return 0
----> 4     return list[0]+list[1:]
      5 
      6 list = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

намекает, что я смешал строки с числами, так вроде берется срез чисел из списка, набирается стек и суммируется

Comment: Прямым текстом пишет, что вы складываете число со списком. Какой результат вы ожидаете от например `1 + [2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: код взят из книги я его не писал. я предполагал что функция будет сама себя вызывать перебирая таким образом список от 2го элемента до поледнего в списке. потом все сложит. т.е. я правильно понимаю что нужно строку return list[0]+list[1:] как то изменить?

Comment: что то вроде return list[0]+list[n-1?]

Comment: `list[0] + list[1:]` --> `list[0] + sum(list[1:]) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Стоит начать с того, что *не стоит* так называть ни функции, ни переменные.
2. Где же у Вас здесь рекурсия?!) ее просто нет.

Скорее всего код выглядел так:

```
def sum_recursive(input_list):
    if input_list == []:
        return 0    
    return input_list[0] + sum_recursive(input_list[1:])
```